# Mvvmcross Android - Error Inflating Class: ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross, xamarin.android

I am getting an error in my OnViewModelSet() function when trying to inflate an xml file.

When calling

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.From(this);
View mainView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Main, null);
```

I am getting a "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Mvx.MvxBindableListView"

Here is the whole exception:

```
Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class Mvx.MvxBindableListView

 at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod (intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) [0x00024] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-lion-bigsplash/0e0e51f9/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:145

at Android.Views.LayoutInflater.Inflate (int,Android.Views.ViewGroup) [0x0003e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-lion-bigsplash/0e0e51f9/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-12/src/generated/Android.Views.LayoutInflater.cs:543

at AndroidCornerstoneMobile.MainView.OnViewModelSet () [0x00010] in c:\Users\David\Documents\Work\AndroidXamarin\AndroidCornerstoneMobile\Views\MainView.cs:30

at at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxActivityView`1<Core.ViewModels.MainViewModel>.set_ViewModel (Core.ViewModels.MainViewModel) <0x000bb>

at at Cirrious.MvvmCross.ExtensionMethods.MvxViewExtensionMethods.OnViewCreate<Core.ViewModels.MainViewModel> (Cirrious.MvvmCross.Interfaces.Views.IMvxView`1<Core.ViewModels.MainViewModel>,System.Func`1<Core.ViewModels.MainViewModel>) <0x00203>

at at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.ExtensionMethods.MvxAndroidActivityExtensionMethods.OnViewCreate<Core.ViewModels.MainViewModel> (Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Interfaces.IMvxAndroidView`1<Core.ViewModels.MainViewModel>) <0x00297>

at at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxActivityView`1<Core.ViewModels.MainViewModel>.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) <0x000d3>

at at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxBindingActivityView`1<Core.ViewModels.MainViewModel>.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) <0x000b7>

at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00010] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-lion-bigsplash/0e0e51f9/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-12/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:1837

at at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.8c1f4311-41e4-4a0f-98f2-454a6152589a (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00017, 0x00043>

at 

at --- End of managed exception stack trace ---

at android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class Mvx.MvxBindableListView

at  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)

at  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)

at  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)

at  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)

at  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)

at  at cirrious.mvvmcross.binding.droid.views.MvxBindingActivityView_1.n_onCreate(Native Method)

at  at cirrious.mvvmcross.binding.droid.views.MvxBindingActivityView_1.onCreate(MvxBindingActivityView_1.java:31)

at  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4539)

at  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)

at  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2013)

at  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2083)

at  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)

at  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1233)

at  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

at  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

at  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4697)

at  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

at  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

at  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)

at  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)

at  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

at Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Mvx.MvxBindableListView

at  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)

at  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)

at  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)

at  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)

at  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)

at  ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 5):

To inflate the MvvmCross classes, you **must** use the `BindingInflate` methods provided by the `MvxActivity` classes. The easiest way to do this is to call `SetContentView()` within `OnCreate()` or `OnViewModelSet()`.

These methods route the inflation via the MvvmCross Binding code which knows how to interpret the `Mvx.` abbreviated namespaces and which knows how to unpack the `MvxBind` binding statements.

The default Android inflater doesn't know about either of these things - so we can't just use it.

Comment: SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main); throws an error as well.       
I tried to use BindingInflate and it gave me this error:

 System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.MvxAndroidBindingResource ---> System.Exception: Error finding resource ids for MvxBinding - please make sure ResourcesToCopy are linked into the executable ---> System.Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an Object

Comment: Questions: which version are you using? Do any of the samples work for you - there are quite a few with lists - if so, can you spot a difference to your app? One outside, chance - is this failing only in a release build?

Comment: Actually... now I've reread your comment. "please make sure ResourcesToCopy are linked into the executable" - do you have the MvxBindingAttributes.xml file in your Resources/Value folder? Is it marked as an AndroidResource?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to use the Current activity's inflator to set the theme id on the activity before calling SetContentView()